# SPFx extension is not loading term store properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, spfx-extensions, typescript, reactjs

I have extension which uses the term store as navigation and on the other hand, I have dropdown list where it has the normal text (SiteA, SiteB, SiteC) with different SP site links on it (href). So, when I click it, I navigate to another site but the navigation from term store is not loaded on this navigated site.

Means it loads the previous site navigation from term store, however after some time (15 mins) when I hit refresh then it loads the navigation.

Not sure how I can make the other sites load navigation as soon as I navigate from one site to another.

```
  @override
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
  Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);
  this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this, () => {
    Log(LOG_SOURCE, 'Navigated event');
    this.termStoreloadingMethod();
  });
  super.onInit().then(_ => {
    console.log("super oninit called");
    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context,
      defaultCachingStore: "local",
      defaultCachingTimeoutSeconds: 30,
      globalCacheDisable: false
    });
  }).then((_) => {
    console.log("Sp Initilize");
    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);
  });
```

.tsx

```
    private store = new PnPClientStorage();
    constructor(props: IGlobalNavProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
            loading: false,
            terms: []
        };
    }
    
public componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({}, async () => {
            // this portion is responsible for getting terms from term store
            const cachedTermInfo = await this.store.local.getOrPut(myKey, () => {
                return sp.termStore.groups.getById(this.props.termGroupId).sets.getById(this.props.termSetId).getAllChildrenAsOrderedTree({ retrieveProperties: true });
            }, dateAdd(new Date(), "minute", 10));
            if (cachedTermInfo.length > 0) {
                console.log(cachedTermInfo);
                this.setState({ terms: cachedTermInfo });
            }
        });
    }

    private menuItems(menuItem: any, itemType: ContextualMenuItemType) {
        return ({
            
            key: menuItem.id,
            name: menuItem.defaultLabel,
            itemType: itemType,
            href: menuItem.children.length == 0 ?
                ((menuItem.localProperties != undefined && menuItem.localProperties[0].properties !== undefined && menuItem.localProperties[0].properties.length > 0) ?
                    menuItem.localProperties[0].properties.filter(x => x.key == "_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl")[0].value !== undefined ? menuItem.localProperties[0].properties.filter(x => x.key == "_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl")[0].value : null
                    : null)
                : null,
            subMenuProps: menuItem.children.length > 0 ?
                { items: menuItem.children.map((i) => { return (this.menuItems(i, ContextualMenuItemType.Normal)); }) }
                : null,
            isSubMenu: itemType != ContextualMenuItemType.Header,
            buttonStyles: buttonStyle
        });
    }
    
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IGlobalNavProps> {
        
        var commandBarItems: any[] = [];
        if (this.state.terms.length > 0) {
            commandBarItems = this.state.terms.map((i) => {
                return (this.menuItems(i, ContextualMenuItemType.Header));
            });
        }
```

This is what my onInit looks like but I get error when I add the code.

"Value of type 'typeof Log' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?ts(2348)
"
and Property 'termStoreloadingMethod' does not exist on type 'NavApplicationCustomizer'.ts

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to subscribe to navigation events and reload as needed. Extensions aren't reloaded as users navigate, instead they are notified of the navigation and the code needs to respond appropriately.

Try adapting this version of your `onInit`:

```
@override
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
  Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);
  
  return super.onInit().then(_ => {
    Log.verbose("super oninit called");

    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context,
      defaultCachingStore: "local",
      defaultCachingTimeoutSeconds: 30,
      globalCacheDisable: false
    });

    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);

    this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this, () => {
      Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Navigated event');
      this._termStoreloadingMethod();
    });

    this._termStoreLoadingMethod();
  });
}
```

---

Keep in mind:

- The `_termStoreloadingMethod` referenced above is *not* a real method. This is a placeholder for whatever method in your code that uses PnPJS to load the term store values.
- The `Log` requires an import at the top: `import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';`
- To see the log entries, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on your SharePoint page

Comment: Well tried with the above code but I see error message, I have updated in my original question.

Comment: @striker92 I've updated my answer with a little more detail and also addressed the errors received with `Log` - hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am bit lost with _termStoreloadingMethod so far I have called the method as like this private _termStoreloadingMethod = (): void => { console.log('%c Navigated', 'background: green; color: white; display: block; size: 20px'); console.log('Context:'); console.log(this.context); } . Please let me know if needs correction or any reference link so that I can check. Also added tsx in the main question where I am getting terms